# How to make a tab menu specific link in Vuejs

Tags: vue.js

Currently I am trying to make tab menu with bootstrap-vue that active dynamically based on which button is pressed.
How to make the link to active tab2 when press "tab2" button?

page1.vue

```
  <router-link to="/page2/" tag="button">tab1</router-link>
  <router-link to="/page2/" tag="button">tab2</router-link>
```

page2.vue

```
<b-tabs>
    <b-tab title="tab1" active>tab1</b-tab>
    <b-tab title="tab2">tab2</b-tab>
</b-tabs>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your question is how to make the links on *page1.vue* active, vue-router assigns the `router-link-active` to router-links when the routes they point to is matched.